# How to set value from md-options on controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple md-select component. I want to set the value of `number.number` on the `vm.telephonyInfo.phone.number` property in the controller.

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.telephonyInfo.phone.number" placeholder="Selecteer een nummer" required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="number in vm.phonenumbers"
            ng-value="{{number.number}}" ng-click="vm.login()">{{number.number}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

When I select a option I log the `login()` function but the property `this.telephonyInfo.phone.number` always is `null`.

Is my data-binding wrong? I thought I had to put the ng-value in the md-option and the ng-model in the md-select.

Comment: Avoid using double curly `{{ }}` interpolation in `ng-value` directives. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-).

Comment: Without the curly bracers I get the duplicate value error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-change` directive instead of `ng-click`:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.telephonyInfo.phone.number"
               ng-change="vm.login()"
               placeholder="Selecteer een nummer" required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="number in vm.phonenumbers"
            ̶n̶g̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶.̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶}̶}̶"̶
            ng-value="number.number"
            ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶v̶m̶.̶l̶o̶g̶i̶n̶(̶)̶"̶ >{{number.number}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Also avoid using double curly `{{ }}` interpolation in `ng-value` directives. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-).